# CSS - Background image and RGBA in section

Tags: css

I just trying to put a background color (rgba) with an image, but doesn't work.

My CSS is:

```
section{
width:100%;

height:400px;


background: url(../img/background2.jpg);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

I just trying to put with diferent positions, like background-image, or just background, but doesn't work.

Comment: Could you expand on `but doesn't work`?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, my error is: Only image appears.

Comment: That's because the background color behaves as fallback for the background image, unless the image is transparent.

Comment: Is the image tiling or is the image bigger than the `<div>`? If the image is larger than the div, then of course you won't see the background color. The same applies if the image is tiling.

Comment: Is this similar to what is [happening?](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Uad6V/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119672/css-background-image-and-rgba-in-section/22119761#comment33557712_22119672), background color behaves as a fallback for the background image, unless the image is transparent:

```css
section {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) url(../img/background2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}
```

If you want to **cover** the image by an **overlay** layer (using `rgba()`), you can create a pseudo-element and position that as `absolute` the use `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` properties to expand the overlay, as follows:

```css
.box {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500) no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
}

.box:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;  right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; /* Fill the entire space */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/N8Mgn/)**.

### Does it have any content?

If so, you can use `z-index` property to move the overlay beneath the content which is wrapped by a relative positioned `<p>` element with a higher `z-index` value, as follows:

```
<section class="box">
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
</section>
```

```css
p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.box:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/N8Mgn/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent PNG as a background image and then you can see both color and image together.

```
section {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rgba within the same declaration

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/b6vzN/1/

```
background:url(../img/background2.jpg) no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

If you wish to assign it seperately as in your example then you need to specify background-image, not just background

```
background-image: url(../img/background2.jpg);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```